# Problems for Extracting data from multiple files with awk

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

If I have 300 files:

f_1.dat, f_2.dat,......, f_300.dat

For example, the file **f_114.dat** has the structure like

**atom(index):**

**114**

**Ave: cosp1   cosp2   cosp3:**

**-0.74     -0.54     -0.37**

**...**

I want to  extract the 2nd line (eg, the number 114) and the 4th line (the three numbers) from certain files (these files are **f_114.dat, f_182.dat,...,f_249.dat** ) among the 300 files and merge them to the same file , eg:

**114   -0.74     -0.54     -0.37**

**182   -0.72     -0.59     -0.37**

**…**

I tried with for structure, the command is

`` for i in `114,182,251,131,183,257,140,191,31,148,192,48,151,195,51,92,177,249`; do awk -v num=$i 'NR=2&&NR=4{print $0}' f_$i.dat > $i.dat; done ``

But an error shows there is a grammar mistake. 
Could you give a solution for the problem ?

Comment: you forgot `do` ... as in `for i in ... ; do awk ... ; done`

Comment: @csiu No, the problem isn't there.

Comment: @csiu Thanks for your comment. sorry for the missing do. When I choosing the certain files, the content in ` ` should be a command to choose, not directly an array like `114,182,...`.

Comment: The problem is in the `for` statement: It should be `for i in 114 182 251 131 183 257 140 191 31 148 192 48 151 195 51 92 177 249; do`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
for i in {114,182,251,131,183,257,140,191,31,148,192,48,151,195,51,92,177,249} ; do 
  awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} NR==2 || NR==4' f_$i.dat
  echo "" 
done > merged-file.dat
```

There were a few problems with your for-loop

1. `do` was missing from the for-loop; 
   for-loops are structured like `for i in $LIST ; do ... ; done`
2. the `$LIST` part was invalid
3. `-v num=$i` was not needed as the `num` variable wasn't even used in the `awk` expression
4. you wanted to merge the output in the same file, so putting `> $i.dat` in the for-loop wouldn't work as they output to separate files;

   - you need to place `> $OUTFILE.dat` outside the for-loop *or*
   - append (`>>`) the output of each iteration of the for-loop to the same file with something like: 
     `for i in ... ; do ... >> OUTFILE.dat ; done`

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works. But the output is distributed in `f_$i.dat`. Is it possible to merge them directly in this command?

Comment: actually ... what do you mean *merge them directly in this command* ... does explanation #4 help?